# Design Question - ORM vs OOP in Dot-Net 3-tiered app -should an object persist itself or only business logic layer should call DAL

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have an app that uses some business objects - like "User". 
I have a DAL layer that should deal with database calls.

Now I want to get User with Id 100 from the database. two options to do it:

Option 1: `User user = new User(100);`

Option 2: `User user = BusinessLogicLayer.UserBL.GetUserFromID(100);`

In Option 1 - the User Class is "self maintained" but if I want to keep layer's separation - it needs access to the DAL layer and the DAL layer needs to be aware of this object (which kind of creates circular reference)

In Option 2 - the user Class is just a collection of properties. both business logic layer and DAL layer are aware of it - but it has no abilities on it's own (b/c it is being referenced by both but can't reference them).

What should be the preferred approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1: User user = new User(100);

Based on many reputable resources like `Clean Code` of Uncle Bob, data structures should always being separated from their business logic. In your first option, `User` is both `data model` and `logic service` and it's wrong.

What will you do if you want also delete user or do authentication for it or ...?
First approach is very shaky to violate `SOLID` principles (specially `SRP`).

> Option 2: User user = BusinessLogicLayer.UserBL.GetUserFromID(100);

You should have a data model `User` and its separated business logic classes like `UserService`, `AuthenticationService`, ... and these services use your `DAL` (which probably you wrote it based on `Repository` and `Unit of work` patterns) to fetch data and do their functionality.

Comment: looks like old OOP is a little obsolete today in the service bound world.

Comment: @Dani: I somehow agree with you about changing insights about monolithic systems and traditional fully all-in-one frameworks specially after appearance of cloud and micro-services, but not about principles like `SOLID`, testability, extensibility and maintainability always are on top of concerns and these are `SOLID` concerns too.